# If read strictly, can an arcanist get free spells from Greater Spell Specialization?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, arcanist

[Greater Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/greater-spell-specialization/) is a feat published in *Ultimate Magic* (2011), three years before the arcanist appeared in the *Advanced Class Guide*.

Unlike a wizard, an arcanist does not expend his prepared spells normally. However, with this feat…

> By sacrificing a prepared spell of the same or higher level than your specialized spell, you may spontaneously cast your specialized spell

Can an arcanist get a few more spell slots per day using this feat, losing spells prepared (a bit of utility)? Is this a good choice for an optimized arcanist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This GM would allow an [arcanist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/) to lose a prepared spell of the same or lower level of the spell picked for the feat [Greater Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/greater-spell-specialization/) so as to cast the spell picked for the feat Greater Spell Specialization.

First, the arcanist has devoted the feats [Spell Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus), [Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-specialization/), and Greater Spell Specialization to perform this trick. And if the arcanist wants to do the same with a *second* spell, he's to take at least the feats Spell Specialization and Greater Spell Specialization *again*. Second, the arcanist is dispensing with his most valuable daily resource—his spells prepared—to cast a few more iterations of a spell he probably *already* prepared. Combined, this is *a lot* of resources for a few extra spells.

This GM can imagine this *possibly* being abusive at very high levels—even level 20 casters still frequently cast 5th-level spells (*fabricate*, *polymorph*, *shadow evocation*, *teleport*, *wall of stone*), for instance—, but, in the abstract, the difference between being able to cast a spell six times per day and twelve or twenty times a day, while interesting, usually isn't, in the abstract, that big of a deal. With that in mind, I'd argue that for most arcanists this would be suboptimal option: the class already has sufficient spells prepared and spells per day and mechanical benefits to be pretty much the most powerful *Pathfinder* tier 1 class; throwing 3 feats at doing *this* seems like a net loss.

Finally, as the question mentions, this ambiguity *is* likely an unintended consequence of the mechanics introduced by the arcanist class that was published 3 years after the the feat Greater Spell Specialization, and it's not at all clear that this interaction *should* work this way. This player can imagine a GM ruling that, in that GM's campaign, this interaction of class features and feats totally *doesn't* work that way, and were I a player of an arcanist PC in such a GM's campaign, I wouldn't argue against that ruling much less leave the campaign over it.